# python-telegram-bot for (v20.x) TypeError: bad operand type for unary ~: 'type'

Tags: python-telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

I am trying to build a telegram bot, I have just reproduce the code:

```
from telegram.ext import MessageHandler
from telegram.ext import filters
from telegram.ext import Application
from telegram import Update
from telegram.ext import ContextTypes
from decouple import config

def testFunc (update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
    print('Hi')
    
def main():
   
    BOT_TOKEN = config('TELE_BOT_API_KEY_2')
    application = Application.builder().token(BOT_TOKEN).build()
    
    application.add_handler(MessageHandler(filters.Text & ~filters.Command, testFunc))
    
    application.run_polling()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The error this code shows is:

```
Bot\AsyncAdvanceBot\test3.py", line 16, in main
    application.add_handler(MessageHandler(filters.Text & ~filters.Command, testFunc))
TypeError: bad operand type for unary ~: 'type'
```

I am using python-telegram-bot api v20.x
I know this might be a naive problem that I might be missing.
Thanks!

I tried changing the code to different format but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it! It was as I said naive error. I was not thinking straight
I have seen the document even earlier and was only focusing on making filters.Command to filters.COMMAND, but forgot to change filters.Text to filters.TEXT.
just replaced

```
filters.Text & ~filters.Command
```

with

```
filters.TEXT & ~filters.COMMAND
```